# OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow -

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We have a scenario where we need an application (external to SF) authenticate to Salesforce via IDP. We have SSO flow set up, where Okta is the Identity Provider and Salesforce as SP. I was hoping that if the application can make a call to IDP to get the Assertion token and use that token to Salesforce endpoint. However, Oauth2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion flow of Salesforce states to generate own Assertion Token.
Is there any other way where the IDP response can be used to authenticate to SF. We have multiple SF instances and wants external application to be authenticated via IDP before reaching out to Salesforce.

Comment: Can't change this on SF side. This is between Okta and your app. If your app can ask Okta to produce a SAML token that conforms to Salesforce requirements, then that's all you need. Same idea but different (and perhaps easier to implement) token format is the [JWT bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5)

Comment: hi @identigral , thanks for the comment here. I need some flow which goes via IDP, which authenticates the user and pass the token/assertion from IDP to Salesforce. Is there any such flow, or we need to write some custom one with our IDP.